# Density of the StandardWater - Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

How can I know what is the density of the Medium of `StandardWater` used in Modelica? With which function can I directly specify the density of the `StandardWater`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, instantiate the medium package in your model, e.g.

```
package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater;
```

Then, create a thermodynamic state, given e.g. pressure/temperature or pressure/enthalpy;

```
Medium.ThermodynamicState state = Medium.setState_pT(p=2e5, T=80+273.15);
```

And, finally, look up the density with the state

```
Medium.Density rho = Medium.density(state);
```

Comment: I instatiated the medium package in the variable section of the Modelica. But I have a problem with specifying ThermodynamicState. What is the type of this variable?

Comment: `ThermodynamicState` is a record containing e.g. `p`, `T`, `h` or `X` depending on the medium.

Comment: How can I enter ```p```, ```T``` inside ```ThermodynamicState``` in the blockdiagram?

Comment: You can't. `setState_xxx()` functions are used in the code. Alternatively, you can write a model yourself where the inputs to the function(s) are exposed in a GUI.